# How does daylightSaving variable is used in java.util.date?

Tags: java

While debugging code, I noticed that in java.util.date, there is a variable cDate which is of type BaseCalendar. How is it used in date or time calculation? I searched for the source and I only could find the getter and setter function?

Comment: You can always find the source in [grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/Date.java?av=f).

Comment: I did explore the page you linked. But I didn't see how this variable is being used.